# How to get the data from array object in JSON API? (React.js)

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, timestamp

I need to retrieve data from a JSON API, but the data is in Array with the type of object. The data are contain timestamp. So I also need to convert it into the format of time in JavaScript.

consider the code below:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };

    this.commitChanges = this.commitChanges.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    // const loginEmail = localStorage.getItem('loginEmail');
    const id = localStorage.getItem('id');
    this.setState({id})

     fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/calendar/list/${id}`,)
     .then((resp)=>{
       resp.json().then((res)=>{
         console.log(res.data)            // line 275
          console.log(typeof res.data)    // line 276
          console.log(res.data.title)     // line 277
          this.setState({
            data: [{
              title: res.data.title,
              startDate: new Date(res.data.startDate * 1000),
              endDate:  new Date(res.data.endDate * 1000),
            }]
         });
       })
     })

   }


render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    console.log( data)    // line 311
    return (
      <Paper>
        <Scheduler
          data={data}    
        >
      </Paper>
    );
  }
```

My console log responds:

[image]

My problem is I need to convert it from timestamp to time in JavaScript but I cannot get the startDate and endDate from my JSON api. Any way or solution that can get the title, startDate, and endDate from JSon API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty obvious from your console.log screenshot. `res.data` is an Array, not a plain object. It should be `console.log(res.data[0].title)`. Same for setState, you should `map` over the original data:

```
this.setState({
  data: res.data.map(item => {
    return {
      title: item.title,
      startDate: new Date(item.startDate * 1000),
      endDate: new Date(item.endDate * 1000),
    };
  })
});
```

You might be new to JS and fooled by `typeof something === "object"`. Well, array in JS is also an "object" type.

```
const plainObj = { foo: "bar" };
const arrayObj = [1];

console.log(typeof plainObj); // > "object"
console.log(typeof arrayObj); // > "object"
```

The right way to do it, use `Array.isArray()`

```
console.log(Array.isArray(plainObj)); // > false
console.log(Array.isArray(arrayObj)); // > true
```

Comment: Great!!! Yup, I am just new to JS world. Thanks for your guidance, its help me a lot.